# Where and how to promote an HTML5 game engine?

Tags: marketing

I've recently completed an engine, called [Irenic](https://github.com/Yannbane/Irenic).

Now, I was wondering, how could one promote it? The process surely is different than promoting a game, because a game can be played by almost anyone, and a game engine can be used only by developers. Aside from obvious things such as posting on Gamedev.net, are there some lists or wikis I could post it to? Other ways?

I'm not really interested in people using my engine, but rather giving some feedback and so on. Just getting it out there would be cool.

Comment: You don't want people to use it, you just want them to provide feedback? In other words you're looking for testers? Congrats on completing your engine.

Comment: post a question to the gamedev stack exchange and include a link...oh, nevermind

Comment: Actually, @amb, that was suggested to me on a previous question :)

Comment: (Although I really am intrigued, and there's nothing wrong in posting a link.)

Comment: are you, by chance, planning on creating 3d features as well?

Comment: Like wrapping up Three.js? Nope, that's too big of a task for an inexperienced guy like me. I only played with Three.js a bit for now, I'll need a more serious game project to start thinking about creating reusable code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I would recommend is:

- There are some lists to add it to, like [this one](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) (make sure you also update the [feature matrix](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-engine-feature-matrix)) or this http://html5gameengines.com/.
- Try following the same search patterns someone would follow when they're looking for a HTML5 engine. Do a Google search for HTML5 engine, see what shows up. If there are lists, see if you can add your engine, or ask the site creator to add it for you.
- You can write a press release and send it to sites like [IndieGames.com](http://www.indiegames.com) who have a section for [indie tools](http://indiegames.com/cgi-bin/mt5/mt-search.cgi?blog_id=14&tag=Indie%20Tools&limit=20).
- Write a post about it on [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/forum/41-apis-and-tools/) like you suggested. Just get the word out there, linking your game engine to key words related to HTML5 game engines. Work the Google-foo.
- Post on forums for people asking about what engine to use.

Comment: The JSWiki is an awesome resource, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a game engine it really needs a show case demo. A full game would be the best but just a technology demo does make a difference. As a developer I don't have interest to build my own proof of concept around unknown engine unless there is some promise behind it.

So, promote your 'Den of Anomy' game and/or provide some examples of the basic game functionalities implemented using the engine.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'll do something like that. I'm writing a small tutorial/blogpost now, and that will include something basic, but I'll probably need a bigger game in order to promote it right.